# Detect circles with specific colors using opencv

Tags: python, image, opencv, image-processing, color-detection

I have to detect yellow circles in an image using OpenCV and python, as shown in the first image:

[image: Picture 1 image]

Once I detect the yellow circle, I have to highlight it, like so:

[image: Picture 2]

I am new to OpenCV, so I was looking for some guidance or help. All help is appreciated

Comment: `cv2.inRange` and `cv2.HoughCircles`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's a potential approach:

- Convert image to HSV
- Find upper/lower color boundaries and create a mask
- Find contours and filter using the number of vertices

We convert image to HSV and then determine lower and upper boundaries to create a mask using `cv2.inRange()`. This step isolates the yellow objects

```
image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
lower = np.array([0, 208, 94], dtype="uint8")
upper = np.array([179, 255, 232], dtype="uint8")
mask = cv2.inRange(image, lower, upper)
```

[image]

Next to determine the shape, we find contours and filter using the number of vertices. We use `cv2.arcLength()` and `cv2.approxPolyDP()` to obtain a list of vertices and approximate contours. We can check the number of entries in this list to determine the shape of an object. For instance, if the contour has *three* vertices, it must be a triangle. Similarly, if it has *four* vertices, it must be a square. So for this image, we can make the assumption the shape is a circle if it has greater than a certain number of vertices. Here's the result

[image]

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

image = cv2.imread('1.png')
original = image.copy()
image = cv2.cvtColor(image, cv2.COLOR_BGR2HSV)
lower = np.array([0, 208, 94], dtype="uint8")
upper = np.array([179, 255, 232], dtype="uint8")
mask = cv2.inRange(image, lower, upper)

# Find contours
cnts = cv2.findContours(mask, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
# Extract contours depending on OpenCV version
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]

# Iterate through contours and filter by the number of vertices 
for c in cnts:
    perimeter = cv2.arcLength(c, True)
    approx = cv2.approxPolyDP(c, 0.04 * perimeter, True)
    if len(approx) > 5:
        cv2.drawContours(original, [c], -1, (36, 255, 12), -1)

cv2.imshow('mask', mask)
cv2.imshow('original', original)
cv2.imwrite('mask.png', mask)
cv2.imwrite('original.png', original)
cv2.waitKey()
```

Comment: this works perfectly, but i was wondering if you could explain what is happening with 
cnts = cv2.findContours(mask, cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_SIMPLE)
cnts = cnts[0] if len(cnts) == 2 else cnts[1]

Comment: Take a look at [this](https://datacarpentry.org/image-processing/09-contours/). Essentially `cv2.RETR_EXTERNAL` is a flag which in a nutshell tells OpenCV to only take external contours, no inner contours. The 2nd line grabs all contours. Depending on the OpenCV version, findContours will return 2 or 3 parameters. So that line manually grabs the contours depending on the number of parameters returned